# Generate environment aware encryption logic with Hibernate and EncryptedString class

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption

Hibernate encryption is very useful, on production, but during test/dev process, I would like to optionally turn it off.

Currently, we annotate our code as the following,

```
@Type(type = "encryptedString")
public String getExpirationMonth() {
    return expirationMonth;
}
```

and we have a definition on the type with

```
@TypeDef(
    name="encryptedString", 
    typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class, 
    parameters= {
        @Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName", value="hibernateStringEncryptor")
    }
),
```

I was hoping that I can subclass of EncryptedStringType, where I can make our code environment aware.
Unfortunately, EncryptedStringType is final.

How would you approach this issue?